# Logger module with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, logging

I'm new to JavaScript, and in Java I probably would do this as a singleton. I need something that I can call from anywhere and instantiate only once.

This is what I have done, but I need some advice to write it in the right way in this new prototype based and functional JavaScript.

```
var winston = require('winston');

var genericLogger = null,
    dbLogger = null,
    viewLogger = null,
    networkLogger = null;

function initLogger() {
    console.log('logger.js > initLogger');

    genericLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)(),
          new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/error.log' })
        ]
    });

    dbLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)(),
          new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/db.log' })
        ]
    });

    viewLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)(),
          new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/view.log' })
        ]
    });

    networkLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)(),
          new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/network.log' })
        ]
    });
}

initLogger();
var Logger = {}; 

Logger.error = function(n) {
  genericLogger.log('error', n);
};

Logger.info = function(n) {
  genericLogger.log('info', n);
};

Logger.db = function(t, n) {
    if(n) {
        dbLogger.log(t, n);
    } else {
        dbLogger.info(t);
    }
};

Logger.view = function(t, n) {
    if(n) {
        viewLogger.log(t, n);
    } else {
        viewLogger.info(t);
    }
};

Logger.network = function(t, n) {
    if(n) {
        networkLogger.log(t, n);
    } else {
        networkLogger.info(t);
    }
};

module.exports = Logger;
```

I can call it from anywhere with `require`, and I expose only few public methods with `module.exports` and due to the require mechanism there is only one instance.

Is there a cleaner way to do it? More OOP? More functional?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question,

You have a ton of repeating code, so don't hesitate to write more helper functions so that this:

```
genericLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/error.log' })
    ]
});

dbLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/db.log' })
    ]
});

viewLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/view.log' })
    ]
});

networkLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './log/network.log' })
    ]
});
```

could be:

```
function createLogger( filename ){
  return new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: filename })
    ]
  });
}
genericLogger  = createLogger( './log/error.log' );
dbLogger       = createLogger( './log/db.log' );
viewLogger     = createLogger( './log/view.log' );
networkLogger  = createLogger( './log/network.log' );
```

I did not test this code, but you get the gist.

Furthermore, in this code, I have no idea what `t` and `n` are:

```
Logger.db = function(t, n) {
    if(n) {
        dbLogger.log(t, n);
    } else {
        dbLogger.info(t);
    }
};

Logger.view = function(t, n) {
    if(n) {
        viewLogger.log(t, n);
    } else {
        viewLogger.info(t);
    }
};
```

Here as well, you could use a helper function:

```
Logger.loggerHelper = function( o , t , n ){
  if(n){
    o.log(t,n)  
  } else {
    o.log(t)
  }
}

Logger.db = function(t, n) {
  loggerHelper( dbLogger , t , n );
};

Logger.view = function(t, n) {
  loggerHelper( viewLogger , t , n );
};
```

After a while I would get irritated by the above as well, and write something like this:

```
var winston = require('winston');

var Logger = {};
var loggers = {
  generic : './log/error.log',
  db : './log/db.log',
  view : './log/view.log',
  network : './log/network.log'
};

for( logger in loggers){

  Logger['_' + logger] =  new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: loggers[logger] })
    ]
  });

  Logger[logger] = function(t,n ){
    if(n) {
        Logger['_' + logger].log(t, n);
    } else {
        Logger['_' + logger].info(t);
    }  
  }

}

Logger.error = function(n) {
  Logger['_generic'].log('error', n);
};

Logger.info = function(n) {
  Logger['_generic'].log('info', n);
};

module.exports = Logger;
```

`loggers` contains the link between the method and the file name, so it becomes now very easy to add/remove/change loggers. This approach does expose a lot more (*all*) the functionality in `Logger`, but I think that would work out.